# Can I configure gitlab-runner to work for a different architecture?

Tags: docker, raspberry-pi, gitlab, x86-64, arm64

I have a **private Gitlab** instance and a couple of private **Google e2** runners (amd64 architecture) for my projects.

The e2 runners, beyond the basic configuration are also configured to run docker jobs using the host docker daemon. Here is an example configuration on how I achieved this (from some tutorial)

```ini
concurrent = 1
check_interval = 0
...
[[runners]]
  ...
  executor = "docker"
  [runners.docker]
    tls_verify = false
    image = "alpine"
    privileged = true
    disable_entrypoint_overwrite = false
    oom_kill_disable = false
    disable_cache = false
    volumes = ["/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock", "/cache", "/certs/client", "/builds:/builds"]
    shm_size = 0
    wait_for_services_timeout=120
    network_mode = "host"
```

Now, I have a CI pipeline that does:

1. builds an image with the tag `someimage:{ref}-temp`
2. performs integration tests using pytest-docker and the temp tag
3. if tests are successful, retags the image as `someimage:{ref}` and pushes it to a repository

All is fine when this pipeline is run on the e2 runners and the produced image is usable on any amd64 linux or windows machine.

However, I registered a **Rapsberry Pi 4** as an additional gitlab-runnger (arm64 architecture), the pipeline run successfully, but produced unusable images. When I try to run them, it says that the image architecture does not match the host machine. Obviously, the images run just fine on the Pi, but I cannot make them work on the prod server which is amd64.

I tried working with a `docker buildx bake` and an .hcl file for defining architectures for the target image, and it did work, but the CI pipeline failed as it indeed produced an amd64 cross-architecture image, but it could not run the integration tests on the Pi (not being able to spin up the images due to architecture mismatch).

So, I guess a solution would be to:

- introduce an bake configuration file (.hcl) to define target architectures
- build both amd64 and arm64 (e.g. both `someimage:{ref}-temp-amd64` and `someimage:{ref}-temp-arm64`
- run the tests with the native arch
- select the amd64 arch to publish the `someimage:{ref}`

However, I was wondering if there is a more elegant solution. I would like to avoid introducing complex build commands and configurations in the project code. E.g. If it was possible to configure specifically the Pi runner to emulate amd64 architecture throughout the pipeline? Unfortunately, I am not very familiar with docker emulation.

Thanks for any help in advance!

Answer (score 2):

you can use *docker buildx --platform* to build image on target architecture
and build image using docker multistage build for compile, test and build target image

on first stage build all to target dir (aka */build*) and on other stages copy that content to use in tests and using in final image

something like that in **Dockerfile**:

```
FROM alpine:latest as build
RUN  set -ex; \
     mkdir -p /build ; \
     echo "arch: $(uname -m)" > /build/result.log

FROM alpine:latest as test
COPY --from=build /build/ /
RUN  set -eux ;\
     if [ "$(sed -n 's/^arch: \(.*\)$/\1/p;' /result.log)" == "x86_64" ];then \
       echo "Arch is OK!" ; \
     else \
       echo "Arch is Bad!" ; \
       exit 1 ; \
     fi

FROM alpine:latest
COPY --from=build /build/ /
```

for now you can run 2 pipeline from 1 file using 'buildx --target test' to run test ci job (build and test)
and without targeting to run deploy (build app and copy it to final image) when test passed

as result you will receive an image with a **result.log** in root if runner arch is *amd64(x86_64)*

**update**
with Dockerfile above .gitlab-ci.yml will be something like that:

```
stages:
  - test
  - deploy

default:
  image: docker:24.0.6
  before_script:
    - apk add --no-cache bash
    - docker context create tlsct
    - docker buildx create --bootstrap --name tlsma --platform linux/amd64,linux/arm64/v8 --use tlsct
  after_script:
    - docker image prune -af
    - docker container prune -f
    - docker buildx prune -af
    - docker buildx rm -f tlsma
    - docker context rm -f tlsct

test:arm64:
  stage: test
  variables:
    ARCH: "linux/arm64/v8"
  script:
    - docker buildx build --target test --no-cache --pull --progress plain --compress --rm --platform ${ARCH} --file Dockerfile .

test:amd64:
  stage: test
  variables:
    ARCH: "linux/amd64"
  script:
    - docker buildx build --target test --no-cache --pull --progress plain --compress --rm --platform ${ARCH} --file Dockerfile .

deploy:arm64:
  stage: deploy
  variables:
    ARCH: "linux/arm64/v8"
  script:
    - docker buildx build --no-cache --pull --progress plain --compress --rm --platform ${ARCH} --file Dockerfile .
  needs: ["test:arm64"]
  when: on_success

deploy:amd64:
  stage: deploy
  variables:
    ARCH: "linux/amd64"
  script:
    - docker buildx build --no-cache --pull --progress plain --compress --rm --platform ${ARCH} --file Dockerfile .
  needs: ["test:amd64"]
  when: on_success
```

[image]